# Copy object without reference using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Recently I was in need of a method to copy an object and pass it to a method which alters the data. Since a class is passed by reference this would alter the class in the caller which I don't want.

So, I wrote a generic extension method which does the trick. Yet i'm unsure if this is a good solution to my problem. I would like to use reflection to achieve the goal. I can't use `ICloneable` and I would like to avoid serializing and deserializing the class. I have also looked into making the `class` a `struct` but will refrain from this since the classes can be way larger than 16 bytes and don't really suit the basic guidelines of when to use a `struct`.

Here is my extension method:

```
public static T CreateNonReferencedObject<T>(this T obj)
{
    var tObj = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

    if (obj == null) return tObj;

    var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        var value = property.GetValue(obj);
        tObj.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).SetValue(tObj, value);
    }

    return tObj;
}
```

Comment: First need to make sure to only get properties that are writable before calling SetValue.
Second issue is that if any of the properties are objects (like List<string>), then you will only be copying the reference.  This would need to be recursive to solve that.
serializing /deserializing would require less lines than the fixes needed, but there are number of ways to attack this.

Comment: That is a valid point, I haven't thought of recursion inside the object passed to the method. Although for now I am only passing classes where there are direct properties it would be better to future proof it

Comment: *Since a class is passed by reference*  ->  Objects are passed passed, not a class. Then, C# is pass by value, by default. For pass by reference use the `ref` keyword in a method signature.

Comment: A C# `struct` is a value type, so there is no `reference` to a struct. ... RE: "16 bytes".  I know that's quoted from microsoft, but how in the wide world of compilation can I know what my High Level Language will compile to without trial and error? If this nugget of esoteric 4-bit CPU nostalgia is about taking up stack memory, the computer will let me know if there is **StackOverflow**.  Hey, moderators! I'm supposed to get 15 points for using "StackOverflow", validly,  in a sentence.

Comment: @radarbob I don't think it is a strict case of know if it is exactly 16 bytes but more of a guideline. Also after a deeper dive as to why I exactly made this function I have found out that I made this to remove the reference from an entity I Get with entityframework *facepalm*. I will rewrite the code to `.AsNoTrackin()` instead so the code actually makes sense

Comment: When solving one's own question it is perfectly acceptable to post that solution and select the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a deeper dive as to why I exactly made this function I have found out that I made this extension method to remove the reference from an entity I `Get()` with Entityframework *facepalm*. I have rewritten the code to `.AsNoTracking()` instead so the code actually makes sense. The `CreateNonReferencedObject()` method is now unnecessary.